# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object' Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

I have code in my dashboard.component.ts,  just like this:

```
this.scheduleService.getShiftSchedule().subscribe((temp)=>{
  this.api = temp;
  var ids = [['user_id', 1], ['status', 2]],
  result = temp.map(o => ids.map(([key, id]) => ({ id, content: o[key] })));
  this.tablePresetData = result;
})
```

And the import library:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TicketService } from '../../ticket.service';
import { ScheduleService } from '../../schedule.service';
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

[image]

Are there any mistakes i have made while writing this code? or have i just forget something?

Comment: Can you check if `temp` is an array ?  I think its not an observable as well (since I can see `rxjs` import). Check on console once and confirm

Comment: @ShashankVivek thats an array man..

Comment: @Silvermind the given error "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type '(string | number)[][]'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

native `map` is only existing on Array. If you want to use map on an object, you can use `lodash`;

so if you use lodash

```
import { map } from 'lodash';
result = map(temp, o => ids.map(([key, id]) => ({ id, content: o[key] })));
```

otherwise you must loop throught the key list of the object, like

```
result = Object.keys(temp).map(o => ids.map(([key, id]) => ({ id, content: temp[o][key] })));
```

Comment: i've tried it, but still give an error "error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'map'."

Comment: ah true, you already imported map in rxjs, so just remove ```import { map } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Nah, i forget to remove it. Btw, thanks @Nguyen Phong Thien it works